Typesetting Chord Progressions With MusiXTex
I'm familiar with LaTeX for math typesetting.
I'm getting started with MusiXTex for the first time.  I'm having some fundamental problems.
My objective is to use the tool to transcribe music for classical guitar.  The piece is "La Promessa (Elena)" - music by Luciano Pizzolante.  It uses an open tuning FACFCF.  I'm assuming that means the key of F major, with one flat.
I'm using a MacBook Pro running TeXShop version 5.32 on Sonoma 14.4.1.
I wanted to start by laying out the F major scale and the chords associated with it.
The .tex file looks like this:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\href{http://www.latex-tutorial.com}{LaTeX-Tutorial}.

Chris Lewis asked me to transcribe a piece called \href{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sLSPBJJ1o2s}{"La Promessa (Elena)"} - music by Luciano Pizzolante.  It uses an unusual open tuning that I've never seen before: FACFCF.  I'm going to guess it's in the key of F major.  

I'lll start by writing an F major scale.  It has one flat, so it falls nicely on the guitar: 

\begin{music}
    \setstaffs1{1}
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac44}
    \generalsignature{-1}

    % F major scale
    %  F, G, A, B♭, C, D, and E
    \startpiece
    \notes \qu f \en 
    \notes \qu g \en 
        \notes \qu a \en 
        \notes \qu b \en 
    \bar
        \notes \qu c \en 
        \notes \qu d \en 
        \notes \qu e \en 
    \notes \qu f \en
    \endpiece
\end{music}

What are the chords that go with this scale?

\begin{music}
     % Set the scale
    \setstaffs1{1} % Number of staves
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac44}
    \generalsignature{-1}

    \startpiece
        \Notes\zchar{13}{C\textsuperscript{maj6}}\sk\loff{\zh{{J}{L}{N}}}\wh{a}\en\barre
        \Notes\zchar{13}{F\textsuperscript{7}}\sk\loff{\zh{{F}{H}{J}}}\loffset{1.0}{\fl L}\wh{L}\en\barre
    \endpiece
\end{music}

\end{document}

Here's the output PDF I get when I run it:

Questions:

How can I get the scale notes to continue up without dropping down an octave at A?
The chord symbol layout is rather obscure and hard to follow.  I tried to install the PMX packaging using TeXLive, but TeXShop complains that it can't find it?  What's the best way?


Ad 1. At the end of musixdoc.pdf, before the list of commands, you find the names of the notes. Thus:
\startpiece
    \notes \qu f\en 
    \notes \qu g\en 
        \notes \qu h\en 
        \notes \ql i\en 
    \bar
        \notes \ql j\en 
        \notes \ql k\en 
        \notes \ql l\en 
    \notes \ql m\en
    \endpiece

Don't forget to lower the stem from the i on.
What do you mean with "obscure and hard to follow"? Which output do you want to see for the chords?
I work with TeXShop, and it does not give an error when I say
\input pmx

I get an error when I say
\input PMX


I get an error when I say \usepackage{pmx}.  TeXLive tells me it's installed.

Inside MusiXTeX you \input packages, as I wrote above.
